# How to solve a system of equations where I need to maximize the final value?

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I'm working on a small economics game and I'm trying to optimize the prices for it. (The context is that I want NPCs to make smart purchase decisions based on current prices, if that matters.)

I wrote out a series of equations that I want to hold true.

$n$ is a fixed number, $A$ is a fixed ordered set of numbers of size $n$, $B$ is a fixed ordered set of numbers of size $n$, $A_i$ is the  $i$th element of $A$,
$B_i$ is the $i$th element of B, $T$ is a fixed number.

$x_i$ represents a variable where $1 \le i \le n$, $x_i \ge 0$.

$$
T = \sum_{1 \le i \le n} x_i, \quad y_i = \frac{A_i}{B_i + x_i + 1}
$$
Goal: set $x_i$ to minimize $\max_{1 \le i \le n} y_i$.

I want to solve for the $x_i$'s in order to minimize the goal. Is this doable by just moving variables around? Otherwise, my current solution is to write a computer program to guess-and-check the values of $x_i$ that maximize my goal.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a **linear fractional programming** problem (see the Wikipedia article to start). After a suitable transformation it may be solved with the Simplex method.